# What is the noun for "feeling of being victimized"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What is the word for "feeling of being victimized"?

Comment: Can you give some context? A sentence and situation in which the word you looking for would occur?

Comment: This question is locked because we now have [fairly stringent requirements](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) for single word requests, which this question no longer satisfies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking for "the word" for the *feeling* of being victimized. But feelings (emotional reactions) vary according to how the victimized person perceives the situation. Consequently, there will be many such words.

For example, "[Emotion Annotation and Representation Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrasting_and_categorization_of_emotions#Emotion_Annotation_and_Representation_Language)" is a list of 48 emotions categorized by situation. If the person perceives himself to be out of control of the situation, it offers:

> Anxiety
>   Embarrassment
>   Fear
>   Helplessness
>   Powerlessness
>   Worry

If the person believes there is something he can do to control the situation, it offers:

> Anger
>   Annoyance
>   Contempt
>   Disgust
>   Irritation

And if the person has generalized negative thoughts about the situation, it offers:

> Doubt
>   Envy
>   Frustration
>   Guilt
>   Shame

Answer (score 3):

### Words

There are a lot of words you can use:

- Victimised
- Trodden On
- Exploited
- Ill-used
- Taken Advantage of

### Usage

> I felt I was being *victimised*.
>
> I felt I was getting *trodden on*.
>
> I felt I was being *exploited*.
>
> I felt I was being *ill-used*.
>
> I felt he was *taking undue advantage of me*.

Comment: Those are all *adjectives*. OP is asking for *nouns*

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps:

- vulnerability
- persecution
- oppression

Answer (score 1):

**Victimology**

According to http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/victimology

However that appears to be a less common usage. It's also used to describe the study of victims of crime.

Answer (score 1):

You feel *exploited* when you are victimized.

Answer (score 1):

There are many words to use, but the usage depends on the context. I can suggest

```
victimized
```

as umbrella term so you can use to explain what you feel e.g:

```
I feel victimized.
```

As a result of victimization you may feel "frustrated", "exploited", "cheated" e.t.c.

Answer (score -1):

I think the word you want is "aggrieved"